# Foundation 5 top bar

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm new to Foundation. I setup a site previously using Foundation 4 and didn't have a problem with the top bar. But now, with Foundation 5, I'm not getting the post-breakpoint (I guess that's how I should describe it) dropdown functionality.

http://www.imdustindavis.com/test/foundation-5-topbar/

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code in the title-area to

```
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
    </li>
    <!-- This line needed to display a touch icon on navbar for small screens -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

You don't need to do anything else to make it work. The javascript in the Foundation.topbar.js file will automatically create and populate the touch menu for small screens.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need

```
<li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
<a href="">
<span>Menu</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Which isn't mentioned in the docs.

However I found your question trying to figure out how to get that to actually do anything. No luck yet.

Comment: I feel like this should be something Zurb should mention. Oh well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you look at their templates page, the code is available there for the header.